# Android json解析の方法を教えて下さい。

Tags: android, json

json解析の方法を教えて下さい。

サーバー側に以下のような固定のjsonデータがあります。

```
[
{"title":"タイトル01","content":"http:XXX0","image":"http:YYY0"}
,
{"title":"タイトル02","content":"http:XXX1","image":"http:YYY1"}
,
{"title":"タイトル03","content":"http:XXX3","image":"http:YYY3"}
,
{"title":"タイトル04","content":"http:XXX4","image":"http:YYY4"}
,
{"title":"タイトル05","content":"http:XXX5","image":"http:YYY5"}
,
{"title":"タイトル06","content":"http:XXX6","image":"http:YYY6"}
,
{"title":"タイトル07","content":"http:XXX7","image":"http:YYY7"}
]
```

これを解析し、アプリ側でリスト表示に使用できるようにJSONArrayに格納したいのですが、うまく動作できておりません。

アドバイスをいただけければ幸いです。

詳細：
　http://onthewaves.web.fc2.com/android/connection/com_json.htmlを参考にさせて頂いております。

```
// dataオブジェクトの取得
JSONArray dataArray = rootObject.getJSONArray("rank");
```

において、上記のjsonには("rank")に対応する記載がないことからgetJSONArray("");で動作しないかなど、色々試したのですが動作しません。

jsonはHttpURLConnectionを使用し、

```
resultIn = urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

で取り込み、

```
Log.v("getInputStream();", String.valueOf(resultIn));
```

で内容を表示させることに成功しております。

しかし、

```
JSONObject rootObject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(resultIn));
```

とすると、Logに

> org.json.JSONException: Value libcore.net.http.FixedLengthInputStream@420e8eb0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

と表示されます。

InputStreamで取得したデータをStringしてからJSONObjectに変換すれば、あとは、JSONObject→JSONArray→for文で１つずつ取り出すという流れと思っているのですが、理解不足のようです。
アドバイスを頂けないでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSONObject` は不要で `JSONArray` のコンストラクタに取得した文字列を渡せば OK かと思います。

```
JSONArray jsarr = new JSONArray(String.valueOf(resultIn));
for(int i = 0; i < jsarr.length(); i++){
   // do what you want
}
```

Comment: turutosiya様
GWに貴重なお時間を割いていだき、ありがとうございます。
検証に時間がかかりましたが、なんとか動きました。
時間がかかったのは、resultInをInputStreamで処理しようとしていたからです。
プラグインを使用し、IOUtils.toString(urlConnection.getInputStream());で取得したもの（String）は想定どおりの動きをしていたのですが、なるべくプラクインを介さずに処理しようとInputStreamで処理をするとfor文のJSONObject時に変換ができないとエラーがでました。
Logでは（String）も（InputStream：要String.valueOf()）も同じ内容で出力されることから処理できると考えていたことが理解不足だったようです。
新たに「InputStreamでのJSONObjectはどうするのか？」という疑問も出来ましたが、もう少し自分で調べて見ようと思います。

ありがとうございました。